# query filter column with other column in the same table

Tags: sql

The table like this:

```
create_adte     info            close_date
-------------------------------------------
2018-10-05  DTS2018100500723    2018-10-23
2018-10-30  DTS2018103001638    2018-10-05
2019-03-01  DTS2019030102931    2018-10-05
2018-10-05  DTS2019030105944    2019-05-18
2018-10-05  DTS2019030108602    2019-05-29
```

I want to get create num and close num in one day

such as above:
3 records create in  2018-10-05 and 2 records close in 2018-10-05,
not create and close in the same day

I have tried like this, but it does not work

```sql
select a.create_date,count(a.create_date) as new_dts_num,countIf(a.create_date=b.close_date)
from dts a,dts b
group by  a.create_date
order by new_dts_num desc
```

Comment: In standard SQL (which is what the `sql` tag is about) you can use `count(*) filter (where ...)` for that purpose

Comment: `from dts a,dts b` creates a cross join of the table with itself because you forgot the join condition. This is most probably not what you intended

Comment: @user8836279. Please show us the expect results.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And what results do you want?

Comment: This is a bit clearer now you edited the question. Do you need to include days where there is a record with a closed date but no matching open date? Like in your example do you want a row for `2018-10-23`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join the table to itself, you simply need to compare the two columns:

`select create_date,count(create_date) as new_dts_num from dts
where create_date = close_date
group by create_date
order by new_dts_num desc`

Comment: it will return the record that create and close in the same day,it was not i want to

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you already know, but `countif` is not a valid SQL command. I think the normal way to handle this is with a `Case` with `Sum` statement. Also you don't want to join (and if you did you'd want to...join, what you've done there is join every row to every other row). So something like:

```
select create_date,count(create_date) as new_dts_num ,
    sum(case when created_date = close_date then 1 else 0 end) as dts_same
from dts
group by create_date
order by new_dts_num desc
```

That recreates what it looks like you're trying to do. What you explained was a bit different. If you only want the rows where they're the same (which is how you explained it) then no need for all the counting/etc, just do that as part of your where clause:

```
select create_date,count(*) as new_dts_num 
from dts
where create_date = close_date
group by create_date
order by new_dts_num desc
```

Comment: it will return the record that create and close in the same day,it was not i want to